Satisfiability of intransitive pairwise orderings via intransitive stochastic dominance

Suppose a function $a(i, j) \in \{-1, 1\}$ is defined for integers $1 \le i < j \le N$. Determine whether there are guaranteed to exist random variables $(X_i)_{i \in [N]}$ such that $P(X_i > X_j) < P(X_i < X_j)$ if and only if $a(i, j) = -1$.

I am also interested in the variant where the $X_i$ have a shared, finite support. To gain some empirical insight, I trained a set of distributions of support size $k$ to satisfy an intransitive $a$. For $k=3$, a solution was not found even for $N=3$. For $k=4$, setting $a(i, j) = -1$ everywhere except $a(1, N) = 1$, a solution was found even for $N=40$.
If you know of any references that may be of relevance to this problem, I would appreciate them! I'm also interested in considering relaxations, such as (1) limiting the 'degree' of intransitivity in $a$ and (2) allowing dependence of $k$ on $N$.
